# csvsimple with minted environment issues

Tags: minted, csvsimple

I am trying to parse a `csv` file with `csvsimple` in order to output values inside a `minted` environment.

#### Issue

While trying to output the value from the `csv` row inside `mintinline` it seems to break the command and prints it rather than the parsed result.

Ideally, I would like to use the `minted` environment (or rather a customized version of it) but it does not compile if I use the following code:

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakanywhere]{python}
  \variableValue
\end{minted}
```

I get this error:

```
./test.tex:32: FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input ` \variableValue \end {minted} \relax \csv@do@postline 
  \csv@next \closein \csv@file \@endloophook \csv@latepostlastline 
  \csv@table@end \csv@postreading \csv@reset@catcodes ' between 
  \begin{minted}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.32 }
```

#### Demo

[image: demo]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{minted}

% \begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
%   name,type,value
%   var1,numeric,32+1
%   var2,string,"text"
%   var3,float,3.14-x
% \end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{
  file=data.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  head=true,
  column names={1=\variableName, 2=\variableType, 3=\variableValue},
  command={%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Name: \variableName
      \item Type: \variableType
    \end{itemize}
    \smallbreak
    \mintinline{python}{\variableValue}
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\variableValue` before passing it to `\mintinline`; also `respect all` breaks the thing.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,type,value
var1,numeric,32+1
var2,string,"text"
var3,float,3.14-x
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}

\csvloop{
  file=\jobname.csv,
%  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  head=true,
  column names={1=\variableName, 2=\variableType, 3=\variableValue},
  command={%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Name: \variableName
      \item Type: \variableType
    \end{itemize}
    \smallbreak
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\mintinline{python}{\variableValue}%
    }\x
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative (and with line breaks). I set the code inside the `itemize` or the indentation would be funny.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,type,value
var1,numeric,32+1
var2,string,"text" "abc def ghi jklm nopq rstuv wxyz" "abc def ghi jklm nopq rstuv wxyz"
var3,float,3.14-x
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[csvpython]{python}{breaklines}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{
  file=\jobname.csv,
%  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  head=true,
  column names={1=\variableName, 2=\variableType, 3=\variableValue},
  command={%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Name: \variableName
      \item Type: \variableType
    \smallbreak
    \expandafter\csvpython\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q\variableValue}
    \end{itemize}
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works wonders, thanks. In order to be able to handle long values, I am trying to make it work within a `minted` environment (begin-end) so that lines can break but am having no luck. Would you have any advice on how to manage that?

Comment: @Florian Oh, no! The `minted` can never go in the argument to another command.

Comment: Oh.. Do you know of another way to have code highlighting with line breaks inside such a `csvloop`?

Comment: @Florian I'm not sure how multiline code can fit in a CSV file model.

Comment: The value itself would be on one line only. I am simply trying to allow line breaks in the output so that the value is shown in its entirety and does not overflow.

Comment: @Florian Added a version with `breaklines`

Comment: Thank you very much. I had overlooked that `breaklines` worked with `mintinline`. I seem to be getting an `overfull \hbox` warning though. Anyway to fix that?